# How to use PHP json_encode with quotes around strings but not integers?

Tags: php, curl

Im using PHP cURL to submit some data to TaxJar API. Im using PHP cURL to submit the data. With the current setup, as below, my integers are getting submitted as strings and need to stay as integers.

```
$fields = array(
    "from_country"=>urlencode($from_country),
    "from_zip"=>urlencode($from_zip),
    "from_state"=>urlencode($from_state),
    "from_city"=>urlencode($from_city),
    "from_street"=>urlencode($from_street),
    "to_country"=>urlencode($to_country),
    "to_zip"=>urlencode($to_zip),
    "to_state"=>urlencode($to_state),
    "to_city"=>urlencode($to_city),
    "to_street"=>urlencode($to_street),
    "amount"=>10.00,
    "shipping"=>1.25
);
$ch = curl_init($url);
$payload = json_encode(array($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer xxx',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

So no matter what I do, its submitting as "shipping":"1.25", which is a string and needs to be an integer and submit as "shipping":1.25

How can I achieve this for integers only? Sorry to the person who voted to close this - just trying to figure some stuff out.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I run that code, the value of `$payload` contains numbers for the amount and shipping. (Not that `1.25` is an integer in the first place, it's a floating point number).

Comment: Aside: Why on earth are you URL encoding all the strings? You're putting them into a JSON text. The JSON encoded will do all the encoding needing for any vaguely sane API. URLEncoding just means the other end needs to manually decode them!

Comment: I have removed the URL encoding. Im just fighting my way through this.

Comment: your nesting the fields in another array, which doesn't seem like any API would expect that. try doing just `json_encode($fields);` or show the actual error your getting, also if you could provide the actual API you're using that would help as many peeps will know where to find the documentation, I can't imagine it's above top-secret.

Comment: If you can't to change type in your array - you can try `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` flag

Comment: Updated the question with the API

Comment: They have a [nice sdk](https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-php) without needs of manually curling

Comment: Not too much experience with SDKs. But Ill give it a shot.

Comment: To match the pretty json use `json_encode($fields, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`.. but looking at the docs its not asking for a nested array as mentioned in my prev comment. https://developers.taxjar.com/api/reference/?shell#post-create-an-order-transaction sidenote you can always plop command line curl requests into https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ and 99% of the time it will work

Comment: How / where do you learn about using SDKs? I got all the requirements installed -> Composer and created the project, not sure what needs to be on my server and how to post from the code they show. It just outputs on the page in a JSON array

Comment: In this case the "SDK" is just a class which wraps up the HTTP calls in a class, so you simply call the classes and functions which should be a nicer experience than manually creating all the necessary HTTP requests. "SDK" isn't really the right terminology here, more like "ready-made PHP client library for the API". Anyway what do you mean "it" just outputs on the page. We don't know what "it" is - is there some specific code you tried using that client library? And what output did you expect instead?

Comment: "it output code".... You mean it outputs the literal PHP code, instead of executing it? Did you give the file you created a `.php` extension? Did you put `<?php` at the start of the file, before the rest of the code?

Comment: BTW your original problem where you say it encodes 1.25 as "1.25" is not reproducible - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/245695ea42e06242c389ce29d32138889dca5a62

Comment: @ADyson yes and yes. I just need to learn how to run things out of an "SDK" or a "ready-made PHP client library for the API"

Comment: Well if you know how to uses classes and functions, then basically you know how to use it, at the abstract level. The examples show you that, Beyond that, you just have to process the data it returns. What action were you trying to perform with cURL exactly? Just find the equivalent function in the library and use that instead to do the task.

Comment: But if you had done the things I said, then it should have executed the code, unless somehow that bit of your webserver isn't set-up to handle PHP files. It doesn't entirely make sense

Comment: I have it working, was a missing cURL Header. Im going to keep it as is and fork it to work with the SDK. Thanks all who helped.

Comment: @ADyson - any good resources to learn how to use SDKs more efficiently than manually writing cURL functions? I just use the way I know how, and rely on it too much. Its easy with the cURL + AJAX routines I run on forms - but I want to improve.

Comment: An "SDK" isn't a magic thing you need to "learn". It's just a class. All the class does is give you a simpler way to call the API - its functions just hide the cURL code from you, so you don't have to write it all yourself. Instead you just call a function (which represents a specific endpoint in the API, usually), and it handles automatically the connection to the API, making the request, and returning the data. All without you worrying about the messiness of HTTP requests. You could easily write such a class yourself if you wanted, to encapsulate any functionality you have to call an API.

Comment: So if you already know how to work with classes and functions in PHP (and frankly it's hard to see how you could achieve much in PHP if you didn't), then you already know the basics of how to use the SDK class. Your only step after that is to work out which function you need from there to execute the API call you're interested in. In your question you didn't actually show the URL of the specific endpoint you were trying to work with.

Comment: Like in the example at https://developers.taxjar.com/api/reference/?php#get-show-an-order-transaction, `$client = TaxJar\Client::withApiKey("9e0cd62a22f451701f29c3bde214");` is a static method which returns an instance of the client class. Then `$order = $client->showOrder('123');` runs a function within that instance to fetch the details of an order. You can always go and look at the source code if you want to see how it works underneath: https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-php . (By the looks of it, it actually uses Guzzle as the HTTP lib instead of cURL, but the idea is the same).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222724/discussion-between-dirty-bird-design-and-adyson).

Comment: @ADyson - let me know if you have a few minutes - made progress